# PHP trouble with preg_match

Tags: php

I thought I had this working; however after further evaluation it seems it's not working as I would have hoped it was.

I have a query pulling back a string.  The string is a comma separated list just as you see here:

`(1,145,154,155,158,304)`

Nothing has been added or removed.

I have a function that I thought I could use `preg_match` to determine if the user's id was contained within the string.  However, it appears that my code is looking for any part.

```
preg_match('/'.$_SESSION['MyUserID'].'/',$datafs['OptFilter_1']))
```

using the same it would look like such

`preg_match('/1/',(1,145,154,155,158,304))` I would think.  After testing if my user id is 4 the current code returns true and it shouldn't.  What am I doing wrong?  As you can see the id length can change.

Comment: string which you are getting is it with bracket ?

Comment: regex is overkill here. what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Why regex?! Remove parenthesis and use `explode()` to make an array of users ID. Then check desired ID with `in_array()`.

Comment: if you want to check if the userid is in the string you can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: @0riginal Using `strpos()` would cause the same problem the OP's having - you'd be matching `4` in *any* id that contains that digit.

Comment: This looks like poor db design - normalize your database. Failing that see answer by @revo

Comment: @Boaz yes you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to have all your IDs in an array then checking if a desired ID is existed:

```
<?php
    $str = "(1,145,154,155,158,304)";
    $str = str_replace(array("(", ")"), "", $str);
    $arr = explode(',', $str);
    if(in_array($_SESSION['MyUserID'], $arr))
    {
        // ID existed
    }
```

As your string - In dealing with Regular Expressions, ***however it's not recommended here***, below regex will match your ID if it's there:

```
preg_match("@[,(]$ID[,)]@", $str)
```

**Explanations**:

```
[,(]    # a comma , or opening-parenthesis ( character
    $ID # your ID
[,)]    # a comma , or closing-parenthesis ) character
```

Comment: nice answer, but I would [use `trim` instead of `str_replace`](http://php.net/trim), as this function exists for such purposes and might be an little bit faster than `str_replace`: `$str = trim( '(1,145,154,155,158,304)', '()' );`

Comment: @feeela Right. I just demonstrated a simple understandable way.

Comment: Thanks, I used the solution you provided with the trim that was also suggested.  Perfect example that it's easy to over complicate things.